# Core Data: Query for objects which have a relationship with another

Tags: ios, core-data

Let's say I have a 3 core data entities: Patient, Therapeut, Event, where as a patient can have many Event objects, which in turn have a single Therapeut object.

So, this code is valid:

```
NSSet *events = patient.events;
NSSet *events = therapeut.events;
Therapeut *therapeut = event.therapeut;
Patient *patient = event.patient
```

Now, I want retrieve all events with a given patient AND a given therapeut. Is this possible WITHOUT executing a fetch request against the database? I find a round-trip is expensive, and I got a handle on a given therapeut and a given patient already.

Is this possible?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `NSSet` instead of `NSArray`? Even if it's an ordered relationship, it would be `NSOrderedSet` instead of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have inverse to-many properties, you can iterate through `patient.events` and check if the events have the given therapeut

```
NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
for(Event *event in patient.events) {
    if(event.therapeut == my_therapeut)
        [matches addObject event];
}
```

This still involves iteration over all of a patients events, but it is more efficient than a new fetch

If you just have a therapeut identifier you can use :

```
[event.therapeaut.identifier isEqual:<identifier> ];
```

Comment: unfortunately no identifier, only the objects themselves